# Guzzle Version Conflict with two composer autoloader

Tags: php, composer-php, conflict, vendor, guzzle6

I have the following problem. For [WHMCS](https://www.whmcs.com) we want to develop a module for the CloudFlare API. Now WHMCS loads Guzzle 5 using Composer Autoloader. WHMCS is ioncube encoded.

Unfortunately the "CloudFlare PHP SDK" uses fix Guzzle 6.
Now I have problems with the cron job of WHMCS which among other things wants to query the current version of WHMCS at the WHMCS API.

The cronjob loads the module for CloudFlare and thus also the Guzzle 6 dependencies. However, the program code of WHMCS Cronjob retrieves the WHMCS API in Guzzle 5 format, which of course leads to an exception.

How can I get the problem under control?

I have already talked to WHMCS, because of div. Dependencies can not be upgraded to Guzzle 6 in the next 12 months.

Does anyone have an idea for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle 5 and Guzzle 6 have different namespaces, so there should not be any issues using them together. Although there are not some many users with such a configuration.

Could you update the question with the exact error?

Comment: I have the same problem and while my module uses Guzzle 6.5 namespace, the error shows Guzzle\Http\Utils in system WHMCS. There is a conflict induced inside Guzzle 6 itself